# Pip Uninstall and Install same package gives 'AssertionError: Multiple .dist-info directories'

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am having trouble installing and installing again the same package. I get an 'AssertionError: Multiple .dist-info directories' error. I think that it has something to do with the pip uninstall not completely getting rid of all the files of a package, but am not sure how to remedy the situation. I don't know what information would be helpful here, except maybe that this is a Django project, running on virtualenv on IIS.

EDIT: I just re-installed python and with it, a new version of pip.

Comment: What is the package? What is the _complete error message_?

Comment: Sorry, I reinstalled python so I don't actually get the error anymore, it was requests, but after I tried with that one, I uninstalled ldap3 and tried that with the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the related pip build directory for that particular package and try installing it again. That'd work.

If you're working in a virtual environment say `venv`, pip build directory will be `<path-to-venv>/venv/build/<package-name>`.