# Flask web development, there is a MySQLdb error

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

I'm developing using Flask web.

1. I want to import `from MySQLdb import escape_string as thwart`
   So I try to `pip install mysql-connector-python` but it can't install.

   The Error is

   > AssertionError: mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz .dist-info 
   >   directory not found

   And solution showed 'Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/Users/kimjaeyeon/Desktop/flask/myapp/bin/python''
2. `from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt` on this line `sha256_crypt` has problem.
   I want to solve this problem too.

How can I solve the this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453049/pip-uninstall-and-install-same-package-gives-assertionerror-multiple-dist-inf

Comment: You could try `apt-get install mysqldb-python`